# Sharepoint 2010 Taxonomy: How to set custom term property via central administration?

Tags: taxonomy

Using code you have the ability to add custom properties to a TERM.

For example:

```
Term term = termSet.CreateTerm("ParentTerm", 1029, new Guid("{0368F902-740B-4855-A4A7-FA8F96813CCB}"));
term.SetCustomProperty("OBJID", "2222");
```

How can this be done using central administration? I don't see any way using the sharepoint central admin to add this custom property to a term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the custom properties through the UI. I hope MS improves the term store manager someday...

Answer (score -1):

You will need to test this out, but you can get to a field that has a tip of "Add Terms"

1. Browse to Central Administration
2. Click Manage Service Applications
3. Select the Managed Metadata Service
4. In the Search fields, the tip is as above.  Try adding the quid??